# Access to pixel values of a tif image using ITK

Tags: c++, itk

I am new to ITK and I am trying to read a tif file using ITK and access to its pixels. Here is the piece of my code for this purpose:

```
    typedef float PixelType;   // Pixel type
    const unsigned char Dimension = 2;
    typedef itk::Image< PixelType, Dimension > ImageType; 
    ImageType::Pointer image;

    typedef itk::ImageFileReader< ImageType > ReaderType;
    ReaderType::Pointer reader;
    reader = ReaderType::New();

    const char * filename = "test.tif";
    reader->SetImageIO(itk::TIFFImageIO::New());
    reader->SetFileName(filename);

    try
    {
        reader->Update();
    }
    catch (itk::ExceptionObject & excp)
    {
        std::cerr << excp << std::endl;
    }

    // Access to a pixel
    ImageType::IndexType pixelIndex;
    pixelIndex[0] = 103;
    pixelIndex[1] = 178;
    ImageType::PixelType pixelValue = image->GetPixel(pixelIndex);
    std::cout << "pixel : " << pixelValue << std::endl;
```

The pixel value I am getting does not match the correct value! I have used MATLAB to check my test image. Here is its dimensions: <298x237x4 uint8>.

I tried storing the image(:,:,1) (i.e. <298x237 uint8>) as a new tif image using MATLAB, and then pass this image as input image to above program. It is working and I am getting the correct pixel value I expected!

I kind of know what is the problem, but I don't know how to solve it. I don't know how to modify my program to extract <298x237 uint8> image out of <298x237x4 uint8> input image.

---

Update:

Here is the information I am getting from tiffinfo :
[image]

Comment: It hard to say if the problem is with how Matlab is writing the image or how ITK is reading the image. With the libtiff library there is a tool called "tiffinfo". This dumps important parts of the tiff header to determine how the image is stored. Please run this utility are report the output.

Comment: @blowekamp : I have updated the question above by uploading the screenshot of tiffinfo output.

Answer (score 1):

You file contains pixels of RGBA, but you are reading them into an image of just floats.

The  quick solution is to just change this typedef:

```
typedef float PixelType;   // Pixel type
```

to:

```
typedef itk::RGBAPixel<float> PixelType;   // Pixel type
```

With ITK when you specify an ImageFileReader you are specifying the type you want as output. ITK will implicitly do the conversion to the type you are requesting. In your case you are requesting conversion from RGBA to float.

By directly constructing an ImageIO you can obtain the pixel type information from the file. Here is an example form the [Wiki Examples](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/IO/ReadUnknownImageType):

```
  std::string inputFilename = argv[1];

  typedef itk::ImageIOBase::IOComponentType ScalarPixelType;

  itk::ImageIOBase::Pointer imageIO =
        itk::ImageIOFactory::CreateImageIO(
            inputFilename.c_str(), itk::ImageIOFactory::ReadMode);

  imageIO->SetFileName(inputFilename);
  imageIO->ReadImageInformation();
  const ScalarPixelType pixelType = imageIO->GetComponentType();
  std::cout << "Pixel Type is " << imageIO->GetComponentTypeAsString(pixelType) // 'double'
            << std::endl;
  const size_t numDimensions =  imageIO->GetNumberOfDimensions();
  std::cout << "numDimensions: " << numDimensions << std::endl; // '2'

  std::cout << "component size: " << imageIO->GetComponentSize() << std::endl; // '8'
  std::cout << "pixel type (string): " << imageIO->GetPixelTypeAsString(imageIO->GetPixelType()) << std::endl; // 'vector'
  std::cout << "pixel type: " << imageIO->GetPixelType() << std::endl; // '5'

  /*
  switch (pixelType)
  {
    case itk::ImageIOBase::COVARIANTVECTOR:
      typedef itk::Image<unsigned char, 2> ImageType;
      ImageType::Pointer image = ImageType::New();
      ReadFile<ImageType>(inputFilename, image);
      break;

      typedef itk::Image<unsigned char, 2> ImageType;
      ImageType::Pointer image = ImageType::New();
      ReadFile<ImageType>(inputFilename, image);
      break;

    default:
      std::cerr << "Pixel Type ("
                << imageIO->GetComponentTypeAsString(pixelType)
                << ") not supported. Exiting." << std::endl;
      return -1;
  }
  */
```

I also work on the SimpleITK project which provides a simplified layer onto of ITK designed for rapid prototyping and interactive computing such as for scripting languages. It has added a layer which automatically loads the image into the correct type. If you are coming from Matlab it may be an easier transition.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your code, but when it reaches to this command : `itk::ImageIOBase::Pointer imageIO = itk::ImageIOFactory::CreateImageIO(inputFilename.c_str(),itk::ImageIOFactory::ReadMode);`, it returns a NULL pointer. I can't understand what is the problem :(  Do you have any idea what causes this problem??

Comment: Looking at the code. This can occur if the file name provided is incorrect or does not exist. I would recommend printing the inputFilename to verify it's as expected in your code. This is a lower level method so some of this type of checking does not occur.

Comment: I have already did that. "inputFilename" is correct and it is in the directory of the project. I debugged the code, when it enters to `CreateImageIO` function, its parameters are : `mode: ReadMode(0)` and `path : 0x0038fc90 "test.tif";` I think the problem occurs here : `std::list< LightObject::Pointer > allobjects=ObjectFactoryBase::CreateAllInstance("itkImageIOBase");` , which returns null, so size of `allObjects` is zero, and the for-loop can't start at all!! I don't know what causes this problem.

Comment: I have tried this code in two different ways: visual studio linked to ITK, and cmake method. It works with cmake method, but not visual studio. However, when I am activating the switch part of the code to store the image, it does not compile at all. It is complaining about switch. I can't understand the switch part used here! There is one case (when pixel-type is COVARIANTVECTOR) and one default(error). what is the third part??